# How to print entire mongooDB collection using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose, and I can't seem to figure out how to print the entire database using console.log?

I know this is probably a weird thing to want to do, but this is just a simplification of what I'm having issues with.

I've been trying to use

```
    console.log(db.collection('name').find({})); //does not print DB

    console.log(db.collection('name').findOne({User: 'apples'}));
```

The first code does not work, but the second one however prints the JSON data just fine. Is anyone able to help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method is asynchronous:

```
db.collection('name').find().toArray().then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: That solved it thank you. This isn't part of the question so you by no means need to answer, but is there a way to only print X amount of users?

Comment: Yes with `limit()`

Comment: hmm i did db.collection('name').find().toArray().limit(5).then(result => console.log(result));
but it did not work.